# Using css variables correct way

Tags: css, mixins, css-variables

I have a requirement to use css variables:

```
:root {
   --main-bg-color: brown;
}
@mixin themeChanges-background {
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
.classOne {
    ul {
        @include themeChanges-background();        
    }
}
```

Which is showing as

```
ul{ background-color: var(--main-bg-color);}
```

Can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong because of which it is not giving me the correct value.
Expected is:

```
ul {background-color: brown;}
```

Comment: You are using CSS variable correctly. Having `ul{ background-color: var(--main-bg-color);}` is the good result and the browser will evaluate this to `brown` later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing (no pun intended) CSS up with SASS/SCSS or other CSS pre-processors.

`@mixin` is used by CSS pre-processors and not native CSS. In that case you declare mixins the way you're doing, and variables like:

```
$main-bg-color: brown;

@mixin themeChanges-background {
  background-color: $main-bg-color;
}

.classOne {
  ul {
    @include themeChanges-background;
  }
}
```

In native CSS, mixins are done just like your other variables:

```
:root {
  --main-bg-color: brown;
  --themeChanges-background: {
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  }
}
.classOne {
  ul {
      @apply --themeChanges-background;        
  }
}
```

There's just one little catch, `@apply` is an experimental feature and [isn't supported by any browsers out of the box](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-apply-rule). You can enable it in Chrome with the "Experimental web platform features" feature flag if you really want. I recommend sticking with SASS or SCSS though if you want any one else to see your styles.

Comment: There is some problem:

    <p>This paragraph is initial black.</p> 
    :root { --text-color: red; } 
    p { color: var(--text-color); }

A simple html and in stylesheet like shown above is also not working. It gives me:

    color: var(--text-color); when checked in developer tools.

Comment: @apply isn't experimental - it's [abandoned](https://www.xanthir.com/b4o00)

Comment: @MichaelPhilips the dev tool will always give you `var(--text-color)` and never what the variable contain because it can change. This is the main purpose of CSS variables or they won't be variable if they are changed with a static value